# Como hacer que mi conexión de mysql en php la pueda usar en todas las clases

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente situación: tengo una clase llamada **primaria** a la cual le hago una extensión a una clase llamada usuario. En la clase primaria, yo llamo en un **__construct** en el cual inicio una conexión a **mysql**, lo quiero utilizar en mi clase de usuario esa conexión para evitar llamarla en todas mis clases, que **extienda** de la **primaria**. Tengo declarado una variable de tipo **protected ($db)** para la conexión pero lo que me esta sucediendo es que cuando trato de acceder a mi conexión desde la clase extendida me envía el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pendientes/models/usuario_model.php on line 17

**Clase Primaria:**

```
class primary_model {

    protected $db;
    public $aplicacion;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = classDb::conexion();
        $this->aplicacion = array();
    }
}
```

**Clase Usuario:**

```
class usuario_model extends primary_model {

    public function get_usuarionum($search){
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from user WHERE 1 ".$search."");
        return mysqli_num_rows($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: pon un echo en el constructor de tu clase padre y revisa a ver si entra ahi.

Comment: Esa prueba no la había hecho y efectivamente no me esta entrado en el constructor de mi clase primaria alguna razón en especifico que pueda ser.

Comment: Pero ¿agregaste la llamada al constructor de la clase padre, dentro del constructor de la clase hija? `parent::__construct();` Yo también manejo una conexión global a partir de una clase padre, pero debo explícitamente ejecutar el constructor padre para que se cargue dicha conexión...

Comment: Una pregunta, el metodo conexion() de tu clase ClassDb lo tienes declarado como static?

Comment: Si lo tengo declarado en static una duda para cerrar las conexiones que tengo abierta por que no se me están cerrado el final del script

Comment: De que manera lo estas haciendo?

Comment: Mi programa es modular todo lo paso por el index.php y al final del script ejecuto este código. `$p = new primary_model();
mysqli_close($p->db);`

Comment: A mysqli_close() debes pasarle es la variable que contiene la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: Pero es que la tengo dentro de mi clase primaria o solo tomo al método estático y lo ejecuto dentro del metodo mysqli_close()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75996/discussion-between-alejo-mendoza-and-yoel-rodriguez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que de esta manera lo podes resolver:

Clase de Conexión:

```
Class Conexion{
 protected $db;

 public function __construct(){
  $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","nombrebd");
 }

}
```

Esta es tu clase primary model:

```
require('ClassConexion.php');

Class primary_model{
  protected $db;
  public $aplicacion;

  public function __construct(){
   //Creamos el obj, instanciando la clase Conexion()
   $this->db = new Conexion();
   $this->aplicacion = array();
  }
}
```

Ya en la clase usuario:

```
require('ClassPrimary.php);

 Class usuario extends primary_model{

   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public function get_usuarionum($search){
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1 ".$search."");
     return mysqli_num_rows($query);
   }

 }
```

De esa forma podrías realizarlo, aunque a opinión personal yo solo usaría la clase conexión y ella la extenderia a las demás clases que vaya a utilizar, ademas te recomiendo utilizar PDO y sentencias preparadas.

Tambien puedes solo extender la clase Conexion en la clase usuario y en el constructor acceder de esta manera `parent::__construct();` a toda la clase que estas heredando.